# Form not updating values in the database if the class of a framework is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, ink.sapo.pt

I m using the ink framework for styling my web application. And for styling form i am using this http://ink.sapo.pt/index.php/forms.

```
<form class= "ink-form inline">
<%= form_for(@document, :remote => true) do |f| %>
   <fieldset>
    <div class="control required validation error">
      <%= f.label :title, :class => "short" %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "short" %>
    </div>

   </fieldset>
<% end %>
</form>
```

In the above form ive put the `class= ink-form inline` to style the form. Doing this styles my form but it does nt update the values in the database. When i use this code

`<%= form_for(@document, :remote => true, :class => "ink-form inline") do |f| %>`

then it updates the values in the database but it doesnt style the form. I am not getting where the problem is. Please help.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
<%= form_for(@document, :remote => true, :html => {:class => "ink-form inline"}) do |f| %>
   <fieldset>
    <div class="control required validation error">
      <%= f.label :title, :class => "short" %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "short" %>
    </div>

   </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

If you had inspected your earlier code in the browser, you would see two form tags (one within the other). The reason is `form_for` generates its own form and that is where you would want to provide the options.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. After ur answer when i add that snippet of code into my code then i forgot to delete the 
`<form class= "ink-form inline">` But now i ve deleted that line. And now it is working fine. Thanks a lot. :)